# How to Decrypt Lua Script?

Tags: lua

can anyone help decrypt this lua script? normally on luaR i can decrypt it by changing ENV to print, but this is LuaT so text keep encrypted. thanks a lot.

```lua
key=[[XeeRazZ Uno]];qgfxnxzdeswjwctpuhbkihpgcmxdchpqzmdvxvmuiqgnypwidfhwhmfobvgigjwasftsbedtlzhogvfcocpyjcimqigfutbmxceozfkeltgvkvlocdaznqsjwtrarybe='om jangan decrypt aku :((';ujndwzpfsnalrwdckkoevcoyrpmbrfufdhayxzxzivrdkgdckirgigvjtwcyctmdjuphcqfwnxdvibzbbjltgjhxwjmxnpjjhtigodtjnbmeuhmsruaviunejrqopojr='Obfuscator Ini Milik Seseorang';qcjvresyxgxosdzkzpaakrpgspbecxcoyjemlwcikqhcgbjidblmcuxiojqosdlznufhprqyrjftvfcryxfjrrijvvwzztkcfmiskrjitjffveecrbjchlkzpioxupkw='Kamu Nyari Load?';rsfckenzbozyclztjwokgmgwkmospmxdjvzpjbrgogugfjqyraunuvspwontqjlkkgwkoeyuwthhdsmojdljakdmtqdkuewuhzmfgtgclbssmdktgadkjhkebhvhgbyt='Saya Tak Ragu Ingin Nembak Gay People';esegzizfcapckncplydgaurzketcnrdyvoeheooihrbjuausihoiujopwmytwybamsbjfxacfvjxapwkmeobbkruohskoojcvmjkzunajbkgzjustcuxytblqenuzjad="Soeharto is first indonesian president. Jokowi is seventh indonesian's president, Itadori Yuuji is one of main character in Jujutsu Kaisen Anime, Kento Nanami is Side Character On Jujutsu Kaisen Anime. Lava is 1 of the most dangerous liquid in the world (cap)";zsqzpfmjxeuztvjmavlicncaupafsoiswtntsjhcswzgmvkjrfhhmkjkahlfomdhajurivmsdmxzvoecvatmnamsriglzgeucrlsqlkimsshbzvzndgjqykufmowenjw={ 1,176,3,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,208,276,290,287,288,216,281,276,217,186,208,208,208,208,259,277,286,276,256,273,275,283,277,292,216,226,220,208,210,273,275,292,281,287,286,300,276,290,287,288,268,286,300,281,292,277,285,249,244,300,210,222,222,281,276,217,186,208,208,208,208,259,284,277,277,288,216,229,224,224,217,186,277,286,276,186,186,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,208,288,216,296,220,208,297,220,208,281,276,217,186,208,208,288,283,292,208,237,208,299,301,186,208,208,288,283,292,222,292,297,288,277,208,237,208,227,186,208,208,288,283,292,222,288,296,208,237,208,296,186,208,208,288,283,292,222,288,297,208,237,208,297,186,208,208,288,283,292,222,296,208,237,208,247,277,292,252,287,275,273,284,216,217,222,288,287,291,264,186,208,208,288,283,292,222,297,208,237,208,247,277,292,252,287,275,273,284,216,217,222,288,287,291,265,186,208,208,288,283,292,222,294,273,284,293,277,208,237,208,281,276,186,208,208,259,277,286,276,256,273,275,283,277,292,258,273,295,216,278,273,284,291,277,220,208,288,283,292,217,186,277,286,276,186,186,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,208,288,287,291,216,217,186,208,208,290,277,292,293,290,286,208,299,296,208,237,208,285,273,292,280,222,278,284,287,287,290,216,247,277,292,252,287,275,273,284,216,217,222,288,287,291,264,223,223,227,226,217,220,208,297,208,237,208,285,273,292,280,222,278,284,287,287,290,216,247,277,292,252,287,275,273,284,216,217,222,288,287,291,265,223,223,227,226,217,301,186,277,286,276,186,186,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,208,275,280,277,275,283,216,281,276,217,186,208,208,278,287,290,208,271,220,208,281,286,294,208,281,286,208,288,273,281,290,291,216,247,277,292,249,286,294,277,286,292,287,290,297,216,217,217,208,276,287,186,208,208,208,208,281,278,208,281,286,294,222,281,276,208,237,237,208,281,276,208,292,280,277,286,186,208,208,208,208,290,277,292,293,290,286,208,281,286,294,222,273,285,287,293,286,292,186,208,208,277,286,276,186,277,286,276,186,290,277,292,293,290,286,208,224,186,277,286,276,186,186,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,208,291,273,297,216,292,277,283,291,217,186,208,208,259,277,286,276,256,273,275,283,277,292,216,226,220,208,210,273,275,292,281,287,286,300,281,286,288,293,292,268,286,300,292,277,296,292,300,210,222,222,292,277,283,291,217,186,208,208,259,284,277,277,288,216,226,224,224,217,186,277,286,276,186,186,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,208,280,292,216,217,186,208,208,278,287,290,208,283,220,294,208,281,286,208,288,273,281,290,291,216,247,277,292,260,281,284,277,291,216,217,217,208,276,287,186,208,208,208,208,281,278,208,294,222,278,279,208,237,237,208,288,290,287,294,208,273,286,276,208,294,222,290,277,273,276,297,280,273,290,294,277,291,292,208,237,237,208,292,290,293,277,208,292,280,277,286,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,246,281,286,276,256,273,292,280,216,294,222,296,220,208,294,222,297,217,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,281,278,208,216,294,222,296,221,288,287,291,216,217,222,296,217,208,238,208,227,208,287,290,208,294,222,297,208,302,237,208,288,287,291,216,217,222,297,208,292,280,277,286,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,208,208,276,284,208,237,208,231,224,224,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,277,284,291,277,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,208,208,276,284,208,237,208,276,277,284,273,297,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,277,286,276,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,259,284,277,277,288,216,276,284,217,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,288,216,294,222,296,220,208,294,222,297,220,208,225,232,217,186,208,208,208,208,208,208,259,284,277,277,288,216,225,229,224,217,186,208,208,208,208,277,286,276,186,208,208,277,286,276,186,277,286,276,186,186,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,208,278,216,217,186,208,208,281,278,208,288,275,273,284,284,216,278,293,286,275,292,281,287,286,216,217,186,208,208,280,292,216,217,186,208,208,277,286,276,217,208,237,237,208,278,273,284,291,277,208,292,280,277,286,186,208,208,208,208,291,273,297,216,210,259,275,290,281,288,292,208,286,297,273,208,274,277,290,280,277,286,292,281,208,291,277,286,276,281,290,281,210,217,186,208,208,208,208,278,216,217,186,208,208,277,286,276,186,277,286,276,186,186,186,245,276,281,292,260,287,279,279,284,277,216,210,246,273,291,292,208,244,290,287,288,208,268,210,223,291,277,292,275,287,293,286,292,268,210,210,220,208,292,290,293,277,217,186,245,276,281,292,260,287,279,279,284,277,216,210,253,287,276,246,284,297,210,220,208,285,287,276,278,284,297,217,186,291,273,297,216,210,223,291,277,292,275,287,293,286,292,208,224,210,217,186,278,216,217};local nau = 'load'; function gbsaxemtchrfzsriztwlolxczsqrqehtoofnmpoyavocgfgwgrhflolxgtnjqbrbuvxoexderedvoeixqvaiganciekqocmhzpvamveavedkwpxipfixmznrlchvopum(...) local urlzcnfadlobljlpyqchqcpnavhopcnzymqrpzcwliwrizxhvkhjhzqqfjlmxsijihvxlswvhsdifvpkbvhnhdpezgxxcnlbccnaixvtxfzkrtltraexdyebnxbbmnrx='';for puxbrquqyxdncfjgbonqwdfhyghdbnkcqbqguqjofttngnbklfgsbzswisyhcglsnwjbrajzzbzrgabrufapznqrwxiwwprgcishikiiogypdihvdilsdsqmjwxdmzwk=1, #zsqzpfmjxeuztvjmavlicncaupafsoiswtntsjhcswzgmvkjrfhhmkjkahlfomdhajurivmsdmxzvoecvatmnamsriglzgeucrlsqlkimsshbzvzndgjqykufmowenjw do if puxbrquqyxdncfjgbonqwdfhyghdbnkcqbqguqjofttngnbklfgsbzswisyhcglsnwjbrajzzbzrgabrufapznqrwxiwwprgcishikiiogypdihvdilsdsqmjwxdmzwk>3 then urlzcnfadlobljlpyqchqcpnavhopcnzymqrpzcwliwrizxhvkhjhzqqfjlmxsijihvxlswvhsdifvpkbvhnhdpezgxxcnlbccnaixvtxfzkrtltraexdyebnxbbmnrx=urlzcnfadlobljlpyqchqcpnavhopcnzymqrpzcwliwrizxhvkhjhzqqfjlmxsijihvxlswvhsdifvpkbvhnhdpezgxxcnlbccnaixvtxfzkrtltraexdyebnxbbmnrx.._ENV['\115\116\114\105\110\103']['\99\104\97\114']((zsqzpfmjxeuztvjmavlicncaupafsoiswtntsjhcswzgmvkjrfhhmkjkahlfomdhajurivmsdmxzvoecvatmnamsriglzgeucrlsqlkimsshbzvzndgjqykufmowenjw[puxbrquqyxdncfjgbonqwdfhyghdbnkcqbqguqjofttngnbklfgsbzswisyhcglsnwjbrajzzbzrgabrufapznqrwxiwwprgcishikiiogypdihvdilsdsqmjwxdmzwk]-zsqzpfmjxeuztvjmavlicncaupafsoiswtntsjhcswzgmvkjrfhhmkjkahlfomdhajurivmsdmxzvoecvatmnamsriglzgeucrlsqlkimsshbzvzndgjqykufmowenjw[2]));end end;local tolan = 'loadstring';_ENV[_ENV['\115\116\114\105\110\103']['\99\104\97\114'](ujndwzpfsnalrwdckkoevcoyrpmbrfufdhayxzxzivrdkgdckirgigvjtwcyctmdjuphcqfwnxdvibzbbjltgjhxwjmxnpjjhtigodtjnbmeuhmsruaviunejrqopojr:lower():sub(18,18):byte(),qgfxnxzdeswjwctpuhbkihpgcmxdchpqzmdvxvmuiqgnypwidfhwhmfobvgigjwasftsbedtlzhogvfcocpyjcimqigfutbmxceozfkeltgvkvlocdaznqsjwtrarybe:lower():sub(1,1):byte(),rsfckenzbozyclztjwokgmgwkmospmxdjvzpjbrgogugfjqyraunuvspwontqjlkkgwkoeyuwthhdsmojdljakdmtqdkuewuhzmfgtgclbssmdktgadkjhkebhvhgbyt:lower():sub(-9,-9):byte(),esegzizfcapckncplydgaurzketcnrdyvoeheooihrbjuausihoiujopwmytwybamsbjfxacfvjxapwkmeobbkruohskoojcvmjkzunajbkgzjustcuxytblqenuzjad:lower():sub(21,21):byte())](urlzcnfadlobljlpyqchqcpnavhopcnzymqrpzcwliwrizxhvkhjhzqqfjlmxsijihvxlswvhsdifvpkbvhnhdpezgxxcnlbccnaixvtxfzkrtltraexdyebnxbbmnrx)(); end;gbsaxemtchrfzsriztwlolxczsqrqehtoofnmpoyavocgfgwgrhflolxgtnjqbrbuvxoexderedvoeixqvaiganciekqocmhzpvamveavedkwpxipfixmznrlchvopum(zsqzpfmjxeuztvjmavlicncaupafsoiswtntsjhcswzgmvkjrfhhmkjkahlfomdhajurivmsdmxzvoecvatmnamsriglzgeucrlsqlkimsshbzvzndgjqykufmowenjw);
```

Answer (score 2):

`_ENV['\115\116\114\105\110\103']['\99\104\97\114']` resolves to `string.char`. It receives a set of characters, picked from the dummy strings above. The characters spell `load`. So `_ENV["load"]`. Replace it by `print`. The code is not further obfuscated or compiled. This is one of the worst obfuscator I've seen so far.

Comment: sorry in advance, i don't understand what app to decrypt lua it for

Comment: any text editor, but having auto format helps a lot for most obfuscated code